Solving the Euler-Lagrange equation in vector form with norm and trace?
I am familiar with the Euler-Lagrange equation to find the stationary points of some functional:
$$I(q) = \int_D F(t, q(t), q'(t)) \; dt$$
Where the stationary points are given where $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{q}} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial F}{\partial q'} = 0$
However, I have encountered this problem:
$$\underset{x}{\operatorname{argmin}} \; \frac{1}{2}\lVert x-u\rVert_2 + \lambda \frac{1}{2} tr(x^T L x)$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 3}$,$\;$ $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 3}$, and $L$ an $n \times n$ matrix. The solution using the Euler-Lagrange equation which minimizes this function is apparently.
$$x = (I + \lambda L)^{-1}u$$
The fact that this uses a vector form throws me a bit off. How can we get to the solution? I suspect it is by converting each term to an integral form. The second term is a dirichlet energy term $E(f) = \int_D \lVert \nabla f\rVert_2^2 dx = \frac{1}{2} \langle f, Lf\rangle = \frac{1}{2} f^T L f$ where $L$ is a laplacian operator. I'm not too sure about the first term, and the trace throws me a bit off, but I think it represents the sum of the energy of each independent coordinate.
